# How to write this for loop in Java8 Lambda

Tags: java, lambda

Here is my code

```
String res = "";
    for (int i = 0;i < names.size();i++){
        String name = names.get(i);
        if (!res.equals(""))
                res += ",";
            res += name;
    }
```

I don't know how to judge wether 'res' equals "" in lambda. Thank you very much if you can help me!

Comment: A lambda expression represents an _anonymous method_ (a method without a name) whose signature matches the single method of a _functional interface_ that is being passed to some other method. Where exactly do you think you can place a lambda here? You could however transform the loop into a stream and use some lambda expressions when calling methods in the Stream API.

Comment: Additionally, your code seems to concatenate strings in the list with a joining separator. This can be done with `names.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","))`. Without any lambda!

Comment: It works. Sorry I'm really new to java8.

Comment: Being new to Java 8 is no problem. Posting low-quality questions on SO that could have been easily answered by basic learning is, though.

Comment: Sorry, I will spend more time on basic learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure a lambda expression is needed here. Did you meant to use the `Stream` API to refactor your code, as follows?

```
 String commaSeparatedNames = names.stream()
 .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Comment: Starting an answer with "I'm not sure ..." and "Did you mean ..." usually disqualifies a post as an answer. To get clarification, you should post it as a comment. In fact, the question is indeed unclear.